# Enabling PowerPoint VSTO add-in by default

Tags: c#, .net, vsto, powerpoint

When I install my VSTO-based PowerPoint plugin, it always shows up in the 'disabled' section and everytime I open PowerPoint - I have to manually enable it.

How do I programmatically change this behaviour such that plugin is always enabled by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set an Office (VSTO) addin to be enabled (in Office), it changes the registry key:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\PowerPoint\Addins\YourAssemblyName "LoadBehavior"
```

The LoadBehavior value must be set to 3 to load (ie enabled) (2 is for disabled)

Office programs normally only change this LoadBehavior setting back to 2 when something goes wrong (eg exception in your **Startup** event code, failed to find an assembly etc)
So you need to figure out what's happening (debug your Startup or do some logging)

In any case, to programatically set this, you'll need to write some code to change this registry setting.

I do it in an installer, using NSIS, for example:

```
StrCpy $0 "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\PowerPoint\Addins\YourAssemblyName"

WriteRegStr HKLM $0 "Description" "Product Name"
WriteRegStr HKLM $0 "FriendlyName" "Product Name"
WriteRegDWORD HKLM $0 "LoadBehavior" 3
WriteRegStr HKLM $0 "Manifest" "$INSTDIR\YourAssemblyName.vsto|vstolocal"
```

Comment: There was an issue in the startup code before and it crashed. But then even after several iterations (with seemingly working code), it does not loads automatically. could that be related to first crash?

Comment: looked at the registry settings, it appears that changes from 3 to 2 as soon as i start powerpoint instance. Then if i manually enable it, pluing works fine. What could be potential issues here? All I am doing is creating a directory and a file in startup code

Comment: with try catch block, i could find some funkiness in my code and i my add-in is getting loaded by default. cool.