# Is there any way to add add-in in powerpoint 2007 automatically?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

can we create some like executable file which add add-in directly to the powerpoint in one click.
OR can we do it programmatically using VBA/VB?

Thanks.

Comment: In addition to Steve's answer, if you are referring to a COM add-in you can find the relevant registry keys [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506597/enabling-powerpoint-vsto-add-in-by-default)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slight correction.  The reg key to automatically load a PPA/PPAM addin would be in:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\xx.0\PowerPoint\AddIns\Addin_name
```

where xx.0 is the PPT version you're targeting (eg 14.0 as in assylias' example)
and addin_name is the name of your addin.

Two values under that key:

```
AutoLoad 
DWORD = ffffffff hex

Path
String = the full path to your PPA/PPAM file
```

==
To load an add-in programmatically, you'd do:

```
Application.Addins.Add "Full path to PPA or PPAM file"
```

Comment: Its not  working!  can you please explain the solution that you have mentioned above?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in 2 ways (AFAIK):

1. By modifying the Windows registry (which can be done from VB or VBA or most programming languages). Keys to look at are listed in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\PowerPoint\Options
2. From VBA: the answer to [Excel: Change addin reference without opening a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9174596/excel-change-addin-reference-without-opening-a-file/9183459#9183459) should give you a good starting point